# Threads in Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I am trying to create a thread to keep on checking the network status of the app so that it can send to my remote database. How can I handle this in ionic 2 using Ionic-native.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install Network plugin

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

mor info [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/network/)

then you need a provider to check the network status

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';

@Injectable()
export class NetworkService {
onDevice: boolean;

constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
) {
    this.onDevice = this.platform.is('cordova');
}


isOnline(): boolean {
    if (this.onDevice && Network.type !== 'none') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return navigator.onLine;
    }
}

}
```

now you can use it where ever you like

Comment: I think that he wants a solution with a service worker to get that extra thread.

Comment: @camaron, exactly, I need a service worker that will keep on listening whether there is a network connection so that it can send some information on a remote database. You know how to do it? Best Regards

Comment: @amin arghavani. Thank you so much. How can I use a service worker to get that extra thread?

Comment: In a nutshell, how can I create a thread to keep on checking the network connection in ionic 2. The if there is network connection, it should perform a particular function in ionic 2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this :

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/read-through-caching/index.html#L95

You will be able to register the service-worker.js that was provided with your Ionic 2 app.

Here you can find more documentation about how service workers work:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers

You maybe need to do a combination of the response of @armin and this one.

Install:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

Then:

1. Register your service-worker.js
2. Create the events inside of your
   service-worker that will hit your server.

Play with something like this (this code need to be added inside of your ionic app, not in your service-worker.js):

```
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';

//watch network for a disconnect
let disconnectSubscription = Network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
    // Warn your service worker about this and create a queue or
    //something to notify your server when you get connection again.
});

//watch network for a connection
let connectSubscription = Network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('network connected!');
    // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
    // Notify to your service-worker.js about this and hit your server.
});
```

I think that you want something like this.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am not asking about a thread on the browser but on a mobile phone using cordova

Comment: How can I put it in such a way that it will keep the network status of a particular page automatically or perhaps after 1 second. Thanks

Comment: Just add the subscription to Network on the ngOnInit hook, inside of the wanted page. Remember to unsubscribe both subscriptions on the ngOnDestroy.

Comment: Thanks Camaron. I have another problem where I can display a model on the web browser but not on the mobile device. see my code below. ............import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ModalPage } from './modal-page';

export class MyPage {
  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
  }

  presentModal() {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
    modal.present();
  }
}

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, lets close this thread, post the new answer and put the url in a new comment here, I'll check that question too.